# Scala eclipse-plugin Project unmanaged dependencies of referenced projects not on classpath after upgrade from 2.9 to 2.10

Tags: java, eclipse, scala, eclipse-plugin, scala-ide

I recently tried to upgrade from Scala 2.9 to 2.10 and ran into the following difficulties:

I have two scala eclipse-plugin projects. The first one has some unmanaged libraries on it's build path. This project compiles and runs fine.

The second project depends upon the first project and some Java project configured via eclipse-plugin dependencies.

Here I get four not very helpful compile errors. Three times the following

```
SBT builder crashed while compiling. The error message is 'bad symbolic reference. A signature in XSBInterRunner.class refers to term interprolog in value com.declarativa which is not available. It may be completely missing from the current classpath, or the version on the classpath might be incompatible with the version used when compiling XSBInterRunner.class.'. Check Error Log for details. de.wwu.sdpn.wala        Unknown Scala Problem
```

Plus another dumping the class path which actually does not contain the corresponding library.

If I manually add the missing libraries to the second project the first project isn't found anymore. Even though it was on the dumped class path previously.

When compiling the projects from the command line via SBT using a more or less equivalent setup everything works fine.

I've also tried to reconfigure the dependencies not to use the eclipse-plugin mechanism for dependency management but directly added the other project to the build path but this also didn't help. Reimporting the projects to a clean workspace also didn't help.

The problem exists both with the 3.0.1 and the nightly version of the scala-ide plugin on Eclipse 4.2 and 4.3.

Any idea how to resolve this issue? Is there any way to find out why the libraries are missing from the class path?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the description, it looks like the unmanaged library is not exported from the first project. Verify that in `project properties > Java Build Path > Order and Export`, the checkbox next to the library is selected. It is needed to make jars visible to other projects.

Comment: Thanks, stupid mistake forgot that when I upgraded some libraries. Any idea why it didn't work when I added them manually to each project?